# PCA on log transformed data

Tags: pca, data-transformation, scales

I am about to conduct two Principal Component Analyses (PCA) on species abundance data and species composition data. I have about 12 different locations where abundance data for over 50 invertebrate species has been collected. The software I am using has an option to log transform and scale the data prior to analyses. My question is, without spending too much time examining the data, is it a fairly common approach to both log transform and standardize the data prior to PCA analyses? Or is it best to just leave the data alone and run the PCA?

Comment: There is no normality assumption in PCA so log-transforming and standardizing your data for is not a prerequisite to apply PCA. That being said if your data actually makes sense to be in a logged scale then you should do it in order to get better insights about your modes of variation.

Comment: OK that is helpful. But what does it mean to "make sense" on a logged scale or how do I know if this is the case? Also I was under the assumption that standardizing makes the variance for all variables similar.

Comment: For compositional data maybe a centred log ratio transform could be helpful (Aitchison's works are standard reference on the subject). I have never worked with abundance data so I can't comment. "Makes sense" is quite literate actually; if you want to explanatory data analysis and a specific data transformation gives you insights it "makes sense". If you look at the data and you can't tell anything, it doesn't. Clearly some transformations for example offer certain properties. eg. raw compositional data don't define a vector space but the clr()-transformed do. Plot you data for starters.

Comment: Is there some reason to do PCA rather than CA?  CA has a different but possibly more sensible assumptions and you'd be taking into account the 'positive counts' nature of the data properly.

Comment: PCA was suggested as a starting point because the analyst is most familiar with it. Another option is non metric multidimensional scaling...I have heard it works well in these situations. We might end up using that instead. AS for Correspondance Analysis, I don't know much about it but seem to remember it but will look into it.